# Jquery within dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficulty getting jquery to work within a dialog box.  I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#dialog').dialog();
    });
    $('#switch').click(function(){
        $('#number1').hide();
        $('#number2').show();
    });
    </script>
<style>
#number2{
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="blank">
<div id="number1">
    <form>
        <p><input type="text" name="text"></p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="one" value="one">One</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="one" value="two">Two</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="one" value="three">Three</p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>
        <p id="switch">click here to switch</p>
    </form>
</div><!--End of #1-->
<div id="number2">
    <h1>div number 2</h1>
</div><!--End of #2-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm just trying to figure out why I cant get div #2 to show and div #1 to hide.  I'm sure there's a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it.  Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind event in `$(function(){...});` in [document-ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function

```
$(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog();

    $('#switch').click(function(){
       $('#number1').hide();
       $('#number2').show();
    });

});
```